# I am trying to open multiple tabs in chrome without popup blocked

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-developers-console

I am trying to open multiple tabs in chrome without popup blocked

```
$('#button').click(function(){

        setTimeout(function () {
        window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');
    }, 100);

        setTimeout(function () {
        window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');
    }, 100);
        setTimeout(function () {
        window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');
    }, 100);    
        setTimeout(function () {
        window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');
    }, 100);
    });
```

> But only one tab open at the moment How can i open multiple tab without popup blocked in google chrome

Answer (score -1):

try the following code block. It will not blocked by browser :

```
var redirectWindow = window.open(url, '_blank');
                        redirectWindow.location;
```

Comment: i used your code there is No Change the Popup blocked appears  !

Answer (score -1):

Use some more code between above two linees code like this :

```
var redirectWindow = window.open(url, '_blank');
//show loader or prompt user
var userFeedback = prompt('do you want to open new window?');
if(userFeedback){
 redirectWindow.location;
}
```

Pop will be blocked by browser. Its good feature of browser for security reason.